# Append text to iframe parent address bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Is there a way to append some text to the iframe parent's address bar? I know you can accomplish this by using HTML5 `history.replaceState`, even there's an approach to this by using [history.js](https://github.com/fortes/history.js/), but it seems it doesn't work for the parent (_top) of an iframe. Also the parent's domain differ from the iframe's domain (I know this may be a cause for my problem).

I want to do this because I made embedded script that I can insert on any website, it mainly creates an iframe with some content on it, but I want to be able to append some text to the parent's address bar in order to be able to share that link on facebook or twitter (I want to share the parent's url, not the iframe url).

Does somebosy knows if this can be done? Or may be another solution to my problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to append some text to the iframe parent's address bar? I know you can accomplish this by using HTML5 history.replaceState

Yes, that.

> Also the parent's domain differ from the iframe's domain (I know this may be a cause for my problem).

You can't do it across domains for security reasons. You can [`postMessage` to the top frame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.postMessage) and have a script running in the top frame listen for the message and change the URL in response.

This, obviously, requires the cooperation of the site hosting the frame.

```
window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);

function receiveMessage(event) {
    if (event.data && event.data.updateUri) {
        history.replaceState({}, "", event.data.updateUri);
    } 
}
```

and

```
top.postMessage({updateUri: "/example"}, "*");
```

Comment: Can you give me an example of how to accomplish this please?

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked like a charm! I also test it using location.hash instead of history.replaceState, to allow support for older browsers.